# SELECT DISTINCT `col` WHERE (`col` is not unique)

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select the distinct values from `table`.`col` where the value of `table`.`col` is not unique.

Consider the example table on this page: ([w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp))

I want to return a list of countries where there's more than 1 customer. In this case it would return only "Mexico".

I am currently using 1 query to get the distinct values, then looping through and checking the number of occurrences with another query. Can this be done with a single query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `HAVING` and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT country FROM customers GROUP BY country HAVING Count(*)>1
```